# Как запустить две службы в websockets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

У меня есть 2 функции:

1. do_GET - получает id от клиента, возвращает html код с данными по этому id из БД
2. ping - возвращает ping по ip.

Я пытаюсь реализовать следующее: Клиенту постоянно передается значение пинга и оно выводится на html странице, а если клиент нажимает на определенную кнопку на странице, то на сервер передается id записи и приходит ответ в виде html строки от сервера, но так чтобы передача сообщений с пингом не останавливалась.

Как мне запустить две функции на одном сервере? Я новичок в websocets и не могу с этим разобраться.

Код:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import pymysql
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import asyncio
import websockets
import os
import re
import random

async def ping(websocket, path):
    while True:
        ping = os.popen('ping www.google.com -c 1')
        result = ping.readlines()
        msLine = result[-1].strip()
        result = msLine.split(' = ')[-1]
        resultPing = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, result))

        await websocket.send(resultPing)
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random() * 3)

async def do_GET(websocket, path):
        id = await websocket.recv()
        con = pymysql.connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'test', charset='utf8')
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id = ' + id)
        user = cur.fetchall()[0]
        response = "<p>id = "+ str(user[0]) + "</p><p>name = " + user[1] + "</p><p>description = " + user[2] + "</p>"
        await websocket.send(response)
    

start_server = websockets.serve(do_GET, "localhost", 7000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я в итоге раскидал две службы по разным файлам и запустил их по отдельности